# funny that when .hgignore is added for Mercurial, this file itself shows up as "?" in hg status?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Is it normal?  So you just need to add `\.hgignore` to the list to ignore itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but you don't want to ignore the `.hgignore` file.  When a new person checks out your repository, don't you want them to get your ignored-files list?  Instead, do `hg add .hgignore; hg commit`.

Bottom line: `.hgignore` is tracked like any other file in the repository.

Comment: +1 for noting the symmetry - Mercurial shies away from special cases which is a Good Thing.

Comment: I can see sometimes we want `.hgignore` to be versioned as well, such as the `*.orig`, `*~` (emacs previous version file)...  other time I may have `.csv` or `.txt` that I want to ignore but my coworkers don't want to ignore.  They can always change their `.hgignore`, of course, but will they commit the file or should they?

Comment: @Jian Lin: If they commit the file and push it, then anyone else pulling will also get their ignore settings.  I think it's pretty unlikely there are files only *some* people want to ignore - if one person is not ignoring it, then it goes in the repo to be versioned.  So the other people shouldn't be ignoring it b/c it's tracked!

Comment: Please see the `ui.ignore` config setting if you need a local ignore file in addition to the normal `.hgignore` file: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement Borealid's answer: `?` in `hg status` means that the file is in the working directory, but not tracked. You usually see it in one of two situations:

1. A file got generated that you don't need to check in, like a compiled binary or something.
2. You added a new file to your project, but haven't `hg add`ed it yet.

In #1, you'll want to add the file or file type to `.hgignore`. In #2, you want to `hg add` the file. In the case of `.hgignore`, it's #2.