# Why my hgignore does not appear to work?

Tags: mercurial

When I do `hg status` I see:

```
[jiewmeng@JM Code]$ hg status
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/Debug/SPA.lib
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.exe
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.ilk
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.pdb
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/EmptyGeneralTesting.suo
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/AST.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/CL.read.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/CL.write.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/DesignExtractor.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Lib-link.read.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Lib-link.write.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Node.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/PKB.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Parser.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Query Evaluator.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/Query Processor.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/SPA.Build.CppClean.log
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/SPA.lastbuildstate
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/SPA.log
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/VarTable.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/cl.command.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/lib.command.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/vc100.idb
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/vc100.pdb
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/SPA.vcxproj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/SPA.vcxproj.filters
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/CL.read.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/CL.write.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/NodeTest.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/UnitTest.obj
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.lastbuildstate
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.log
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/cl.command.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/link.command.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/link.read.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/link.write.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/mt.command.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/mt.read.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/mt.write.1.tlog
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/vc100.idb
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/vc100.pdb
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/source/UnitTest.cpp
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/source/Parser.cpp
M examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/source/Parser.h
A .hgignore
? examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Debug/SPA.write.1.tlog
? examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/SPA/Parser.h
? examples/SampleTestingSolution/EmptyGeneralTesting/UnitTesting/Debug/UnitTesting.write.1.tlog
```

So I made `.hgignore` look like

```
syntax: glob

*.lib
*.tlog
*.log
*.obj
*.tlog
*.idb
*.pdb
*.exe
*.ilk
*.filters
```

When I do hg status again, I see a similar/non noticeable difference in output. Why? I expected all those to be gone from `hg status`

Comment: When I run into things like this I use procmon (www.systeminternals.com) to check which files are used and how the the program searches for them. It is usually faster than searching documentation, settings etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already added those files, you need to "`hg forget`" them before seing the hgignore directives applied.
See "[What is the difference between `hg forget` and `hg remove?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101167/what-is-the-difference-between-hg-forget-and-hg-remove)": `hg remove -Af` (ie `hg forget`) will remove them without deleting them from the working directory.
See also [this thread](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2009-August/027072.html):

> Un-tracked files show up with a question mark in '`hg status`', unless they are matched by the `.hgignore` file.

Comment: Ok I dont really get what forgot or remove does actually, remove will remove the file right? I understand `forget` is a shorthand for `remove -Af`? I did `remove -Af` and `hg status` now gives similar output except lines are prepended with `R`. Files doesnt appear deleted but will they be removed from the repo or something?

Comment: Tried commiting and then hg status again ... returned to similar output with ? in front of those lines. They should be matched by my .hgignore?

Comment: @JiewMeng `hg forget` is a shortcut for `hg remove -Af`, which un-track the file while keeping it on the disk. `hg status` should display it with a '`?`' unless your `.hgignore` matches that untracked file (in which case, `hg status` won't display it at all)

Comment: @JiewMeng see an example at http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-03-20/hgignore-for-mac-os-x-applications. Put your `.hgignore` at the root directory of your repo. (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4965250/6309)

Comment: @JiewMeng did you hg add the `.hgignore` file? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472866/funny-that-when-hgignore-is-added-for-mercurial-this-file-itself-shows-up-as). You don't need to add it for hgignore to work, but if it does work, you should add it and commit it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/965344/6309)